# SQL WHERE statements, where column may be value or may be NULL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQL table (in SQLite3) in which I am trying to aggregate information from several other tables, and records in one table may or may not have a corresponding record in another table. My query is supposed to include in the aggregate table both records with and without linked information. For example:

```
            CREATE TABLE all_households AS
                SELECT pop.uid AS pop_uid,
                       pop.surname,
                       pop.given,
                       pop.age,
                       pop.real_property,

                       farm.uid AS farm_uid,
                       farm.improved_acres,
                       farm.unimproved_acres,
                       farm.cash_value,
                       farm.corn,
                       farm.cotton

                       FROM pop, farm
                       WHERE pop.farm_id = farm.uid;
```

This is looking at data from census schedules. Everybody in the census will have the basic `pop` information -- surname, given name, value of real property -- but not everybody has a farm. Only certain individuals have a value in the `farm_id` column on `pop`, corresponding to the record of that person's farm on `farm`; otherwise `farm_id` is NULL.

But naturally, the above query will fetch only those individuals for whom `pop.farm_id = farm.uid` -- that is, who have farms, and have values for `farm_id`. The farmless individuals are excluded, and I want to include them, with empty values for the relevant `farm` columns in `all_households`.

Now, I know I could solve this, and have so far, with separate SELECT statements for each linked column, like so:

```
            CREATE TABLE all_households AS
                SELECT uid AS pop_uid,
                       surname,
                       given,
                       age,
                       real_property,

                       (SELECT uid FROM farm WHERE pop.farm_id = farm.uid) AS farm_uid,
                       (SELECT improved_acres FROM farm WHERE pop.farm_id = farm.uid) AS improved_acres,
                       (SELECT unimproved_acres FROM farm WHERE pop.farm_id = farm.uid) AS unimproved_acres,
                       (SELECT cash_value FROM farm WHERE pop.farm_id = farm.uid) AS cash_value,
                       (SELECT corn FROM farm WHERE pop.farm_id = farm.uid) AS corn,
                       (SELECT cotton FROM farm WHERE pop.farm_id = farm.uid) AS cotton

                       FROM pop;
```

But this seems terribly clunky and inelegant. So, I wondered if there was a way to make the first query above pick up entries from `pop` where `farm_id` was NULL:

```
            WHERE pop.farm_id = farm.uid OR pop.farm_id IS NULL;
```

But then things went very haywire, and I'm not sure why. In my real, unsimplified query, I'm actually dealing with four tables, each with a column on `pop` that may be a value or may be NULL, and though the first query above as written took only seconds, the query with this WHERE hung. Forever. And when I came back, it had died with the error that "database or disk is full." So whatever I did, I seem to have elicited some kind of endless loop. I tried alternately:

```
            WHERE (CASE WHEN pop.farm_id IS NOT NULL THEN pop.farm_id = farm.uid ELSE 1 END);
```

But this had the same result as before. Can anybody shed any light on what I'm doing wrong, or what I might do better? Thanks.

Comment: I believe you're looking for an OUTER JOIN, but I am not sure how to do that in your flavor of SQL.

Comment: Read up on Types ofJoins.  Inner, Full Outer, Left, RIght...  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html is a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt to use `farm_id IS NULL` was slow because the database attempted to give you the combination of *each* `farm` record with *each* `pop` record with the `NULL` value.
Furthermore, [optimizing constraints with OR is not easy](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#or_opt) and was done with a temporary table.

To get all matched/joined records, and all records from the first table with no corresponding farm, combine two queries with [UNION ALL](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```
SELECT pop. ..., farm. ...
FROM pop JOIN farm ON pop.farm_id = farm.uid

UNION ALL

SELECT pop. ..., NULL, NULL, ...
FROM pop
WHERE pop.farm_id IS NULL
```

This construct is called an [outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join) and is supported directly in most SQL databases (SQLite supports only left joins, which is what you want here):

```
SELECT pop. ..., farm. ...
FROM pop LEFT OUTER JOIN farm ON pop.farm_id = farm.uid
```

Please note that an outer join actually returns all *unmatched* records, so this will also return `pop` records with an invalid `farm_id`.